# How do I send requests to two processes in Apache2?

Tags: apache, apache2

I got two servers, a custom Rust server I've created, listening to port 4848, and a Gitea server listening at 3000. I can connect to both of these just fine if I input the IP and port directly, but obviously this is not ideal. How can I direct *.domain.exmaple to the process at 4848, and gitea.domain.example at 3000?

I'm using Ubuntu 22

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find a solution. I edited my main configuration file to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@email
    ServerName gitea.domain.example
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@email
    ServerName domain.example
    ServerAlias *.domain.example
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4848/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4848/
</VirtualHost>
```